# DurableOrchestrationClient.GetStatusAsync() always null for Durable Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a queue trigger azure function with DurableOrchestrationClient.  I am able to start a new execution of my orchestration function, which triggers multiple activitytrigger functions and waits for them all to process. Everything works great.

My issue is that I am unable to check on the status of my orchestration function("TestFunction").  GetStatusAsync always returns as null. I need to know when the orchestration function is actually complete and process the return object (bool).

```
public static async void Run([QueueTrigger("photostodownload", Connection = "QueueStorage")]PhotoInfo photoInfo, [OrchestrationClient]DurableOrchestrationClient starter, TraceWriter log)
{
     var x = await starter.StartNewAsync("TestFunction", photoInfo);
     Thread.Sleep(2 * 1000);
     var y = await starter.GetStatusAsync(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`StartNewAsync` enqueues a message into the control queuee, it doesn't mean that the orchestration starts immediately.

`GetStatusAsync` returns `null` if the instance either doesn't exist or has not yet started running. So, probably the orchestration just doesn't start yet during those 2 seconds of sleep that you have.

Rather than having a fixed wait timeout, you should either periodically poll the status of your orchestration, or send something like a `Done` event from the orchestration as the last step of the workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  With your suggestion I was able to poll periodically and Status finally came back as Running.  My new issue is that even after the orchestration function exits returning a value (bool) , the status remains "Running" and the output remains null.  I have a break-point on the orchestration function return statement so I am 100% sure it is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using function 1.0 or 2.0? A similar issue has been reported for Function 2.0 runtime on Github.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/126

Also when you say everything works great do you mean activityTrigger functions complete execution?

Are you running functions locally or is it deployed on Azure?

Comment: My issue was that my Orchestration Function was making asynchronous calls ( HttpClient.SendAsync()).  This bugs out the function and it will always report the status to the orchestration client as Running.  Once I removed all async calls in the Orchestration Function, it reported the status correctly.